How to solve the heat equation with time-dependent coefficient on a finite interval?
I am trying to solve the following PDE for $x\in[0,L]$:
$$\partial_t h(x,t) = \partial_x^2 h(x,t) + f(t) \partial_x h(x,t) $$
with boundary conditions
$$ h(0,t) = 0 = h(L,t) $$
The initial condition $h(x,0)$ is arbitrary.
I know how to solve this on the real line (a transformation $z\equiv x + \int f(t)$ recovers the standard heat equation in $z$ and $t$) but not on the finite interval where I need to respect the Dirichlet boundary conditions.  Is there a general solution for arbitrary $f(t)$?
Edit 1: removed comment that I cared mainly about the limit $h(x,\infty)$

Maybe I am mistaken so take this as a question: there is a maximum principle that states that for some PDEs the maximum value could only be achieved at the edges. I am not really sure if it apply to the heat equation, but if its zero in both extremes, nothing should happen, thinking in the example of a metallic rod with heat applied on one extreme, the full "rod" is at same temperature with your initial conditions so no heat moving within from hot to cold parts.

Certainly with f(t) constant, h(x,t) goes to zero in the limit.  Your question is a good one, and I'm not sure how to answer it; I don't know if this is true for arbitrary f(t) or not.
Also, I admit that the actual setting I am interested in has a non-homogeneous forcing term that will definitely keep the function non-zero.  But I figured I need to determine how to solve the homogeneous problem first...

what I don't understand is how $f(t)$ would be participating if $h(0,t)=h(L,t)=0$? it somehow affect the inbetween without starting/finishing since its initial conditions would be equivalently zero? $f(t)\partial _xh({0,,L},t)=0$

@Joako You are right, at least as far as convergence of the 2-norm, the values of the function $f$ don't matter (see my answer). And yes, by the way, there is an analogue of the maximum principle for the heat equation as well. For a statement and proof of this principle in one spacial dimension (generlizing to arbitrary spacial dimensions is not difficult and is done in L. C. Evans PDE book), see chapter 8.3 of "Introduction to Partial Differential Equations" by Peter J. Olver. If you can't find a copy online, I'll be happy to provide a link to it on Google Drive.

The solution exists.  What do you mean under a general solution? A representation as series?

Something analytic; a series representation would be useful.  And while I also think a solution exists, another respondent has conjectured that it does not.

If you don't care about solving it exactly, and only care about limiting behavior, you can carry on in the spirit of this question and define
$$E(t)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^L {u(t,x)}^2\mathrm dx$$
And find
$$\dot{E}(t)=\int_{0}^Lu(t,x)\partial_tu(t,x)\mathrm dx \\ =\int_0^Lu(t,x)\big(\partial_x^2 u(t,x)+f(t)\partial_xu(t,x)\big)\mathrm dx$$
Using integration by parts on the first term and straightforward integration of a derivative on the second, we get
$$\dot{E}(t)=\big(u(t,x)\partial_xu(t,x)\big)\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=L}-\int_{0}^L{\partial_xu(t,x)}^2\mathrm dx+f(t)\big(u(t,x)\big)\bigg|^{x=L}_{x=0}$$
Using the boundary conditions $u(t,0)=0~,~u(t,L)=0$, this gives us
$$\dot{E}(t)=-\int_{0}^L{\partial_xu(t,x)}^2\mathrm dx\leq 0$$
As detailed in the answer of my other question, a mixture of Poincaré's inequality and Grönwall's inequality implies that $E\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$, in other words, the thermal energy inside the rod goes to zero in the long-time limit. In the case of the classical heat equation $f\equiv 0$, this necessarily implies that $u(t,x)\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$ for all $x\in(0,L)$, not just the 2-norm $\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_2\to 0 $ as $t\to\infty$. (I should add that showing this is not trivial, hence the length of the discussion on the other question.)
In this case showing the convergence to $0$ of the 2-norm is not difficult (as I have just demonstrated) but showing the stronger pointwise convergence (i.e $u(t,x)\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$ for all $x\in(0,L)$) would essentially require one to repeat the detailed analysis of my linked answer in the case $f\neq 0$. I suspect that one probably requires certain "nice" properties of $f$, though I don't know what those properties are yet - probably boundedness and a few other things, I don't know.
Hope this helps, for now.

Thank you.  This response is certainly helpful to demonstrate the solution must be going to zero regardless of $f(t)$.  It makes me recognize that I am interested in the solution for an arbitrary initial condition for all $t$, not just in the limit (I shouldn't have given that caveat).

Your boundary conditions imply that for each fixed $t$, the function $h(x,t)$ can be extended as a periodic function of $x$ with period $L$, e.g. $L=2\pi$. Consider then the expansion of  $h(x,t)$ as a Fourier series in $x$,  whose coefficients depend on $t$.
Write $h(x,t)=\sum_k c_k(t) e^{i k x}$.
and insert into the heat equation, which leads to the requirement
$\dot c_k= (-k^2 + i k f(t)) c_k$. Thus set $c_k(t)= c_k(0) e^{- k^2t + i k F(t)}$ where $F(t)$ is the antiderivative of $f(t)$.
This produces  a formal periodic solution  to the heat equation that can be matched to the initial datum $h(x,0)=f(x)= \sum_k c_k(0) e^{i kx}$.
Now let's try to satisfy the boundary conditions.
Consider the time-varying left-endpoint value $C(t)= h(0,t)= \sum_k c_k(t)$.
Note that the original heat equation has homogeneous solutions of the type $h(x,t)= C=$ constant in $x$ AND $t$.  Since you have the freedom to subtract such expressions you can modify the periodic function constructed above so that its endpoint values at $x=0, 2\pi$ are both 0 at time $t=0$. Unfortunately $h(0,t)=C(t)$ will generally not vanish at later times $t$. So I think your boundary conditions are generally impossible to satisfy.
